# How to get old Dock Exposé on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, dock, expose

Dock Exposé was a Snow Leopard feature which allowed users to click on an app on the Dock and, holding that click, windows of that app would be exposed. On Mountain Lion, Dock Exposé doesn't seem to be available anymore. Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would make scrolling up (or dragging up with two fingers) over an icon show app Exposé:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock scroll-to-open -bool true
osascript -e 'quit app "Dock"'
```

Comment: Double tapping works when done with two fingers

Answer (score 5):

Thankfully, this feature isn't completely gone. It has just, for some reason, been whisked away into the depths of less-than-obvious multi-touch gestures in OS X Lion and newer. You now have to double-tap an app icon on the Dock with two fingers to activate Dock Exposé.

I'm not sure if this gesture ever existed on OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: It doesn't work if the smart zoom gesture is disabled in the trackpad preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You can also choose a key sequence for that using the Mission Control Preference Pane.  The default is <kbd>⌃↓</kbd>.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for: "app exposè" is different from "dock exposè" since the first one requires an app to be activated before exposing its windows